# Transparant weight paint in blender 2.8

Tags: weight-painting

I'm having problems with weight paint in blender 2.8.
I want to be able to paint tough a mesh with Xray so I can paint the inside parts om models. I can't get it to work in 2.8 like it was in 2.79.

Comment: maybe you're talking about the 2D Falloff option in the N panel?

Comment: I tried looking, where do I find it?

Comment: go in your 3D view, press N to open the right panel, then Too tab > Brush > Options > 2D Falloff, and disable Front Face Only

Comment: ^^ did exactly this (disabled Frontface Falloff checkbox), still does not paint through mesh. What is going on with blender?